# Cannot resolve symbol 'BoundingBoxE6'

Tags: android, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid, bounding-box

I'm trying to implement a limited scrollable area for my map on android. I'm using osmdroid. Came across BoundingBoxE6. However, when I included `import org.osmdroid.util.BoundingBoxE6;` , it tells me: "Cannot resolve symbol 'BoundingBoxE6' ". 
Do I have to put an implementation to my gradle? Or a permission to my manifest?

Comment: Can I ask where did come across the BoundingBoxE6? It might be an error on wiki or someting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bounding BoundingBoxE6 was removed and replaced with BoundingBox (without E6), the package is the same ( org.osmdroid.util.BoundingBox ).

Comment: Thanks for this! Got the snippet here: https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/Osmdroid-Plus#support-for-tilesources-bundled-within-the-apk

Comment: Btw, can you take a look at my new question and se eif you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529648/no-map-displayed-when-using-bounding-box-setscrollablearealimitdouble

thanks :)